# Creative D200, MacBook Pro and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, macbook-pro, drivers, creative

I have a problem with bluetooth speakers Creative D200 on MacBook Pro running Windows 7.

This question appends on:
[Broadcom bluetooth driver for Windows 7 on MacBook Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/212579/broadcom-bluetooth-driver-for-windows-7-on-macbook-pro)

Do You have any solution for MacBook Pro 2011 (8.1)? There is Apple Broadcom driver in bootcamp, but I cannot find native name of the bluetooth device (to find driver for another notebook like acer or hp.

I used sound driver from the driver package in thread [Broadcom bluetooth driver for Windows 7 on MacBook Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/212579/broadcom-bluetooth-driver-for-windows-7-on-macbook-pro) - it connected and installed driver bluetooth AV device and bluetooth remote control, but it doesnt play anything via d200, I cannot find it in Sound properties in control panel. In bluetooth setting is speaker icon, but after right clicking it - there is only properties, make a shortcut, remove and help (there should be probably also something like connect)...

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

> How do I install a Toshiba stack?
>
> This worked on my Mackbook air mid - 2011Windows 7 x64. Be aware that you will loose the "magic scrolling" in case you are using a bluetooth magic mouse. Otherwise all bluetooth devices have been working as a chram with the Toshiba stack.
>
> To make it work, follow this steps:
>   http://linkopia.blogspot.com/2009/05/a2dp-stereo-bluetooth-on-win-xp-boot.html
>
> But instead of downloading the toshiba stack in the above link, download the x64 stack you will find in the link bellow:
>
> http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/bluetooth/pages/disclaimer.php?dt=bts&download=3-64bit
>
> once you have "tricked" the stacks restart and run the Toshiba assistant

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17665845#17665845)